Should we get rid of [breakfast]?
I was editing a question and stumbled upon breakfast. Did some investigation and looking at the ~50 questions tagged I can't see a good reason to keep it, it doesn't add any specificity to the questions.
Should we get rid of it?

but I was told it's the most important meal of the day

For what it's worth, tags aren't really about adding specificity. The question itself should provide all the specifics, and if someone has to look to the tags to understand, something has gone wrong. They're more about organization and searching: take a commonly relevant/understood topic at an appropriate level of granularity, mark questions for later searching, etc. In particular, it needs to be reasonably obvious when a tag should and shouldn't apply, and that's the test that breakfast mostly fails.
So, probably the tag should go away, but not immediately? It's definitely a pretty vague, culturally defined category that doesn't mean much in most cases. The actual common aspect is probably more that that breakfast foods are typically possible to either make ahead or make quickly. See for example questions like Cooking rice overnight?.
I'd feel better about dropping the tag if we had a replacement tag to use for prepping overnight/way ahead, and possibly one for trying to make it possible to prep something quickly, including for breakfast (there's obviously some overlap between the two, and I don't know the right answer). There's also a couple questions that are only tagged breakfast, and it's a lot easier to retag those while you can still search for breakfast.

I like the idea of having a tag for prep-ahead or similar. Most of the other breakfast questions could just exist with other better tags. Since this is not a recipe sharing website I believe there's no need to organize questions by meal type.

Since we're here, any suggestions for a tag? What would be easier / more generic, [meal prep] or something else?
